# Is this a bug in Python inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, language-features

I'm not sure if the output of this code is correct or a bug:

```
class F:
  """An abstract class"""
  list_of_secrets = []
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def getSecret(self):
    return self.list_of_secrets

class F_None(F):
  pass

class F_Some(F):
  def __init__(self):
    self.list_of_secrets.append("secret value!")

x = F_Some()
print "x:",x.getSecret()

y = F_None()
print "y:",y.getSecret()
```

The output using python 2.7.3:

`x: ['secret value!']`

`y: ['secret value!']`

I think it should output:

`x: ['secret value!']`

`y: []`

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the same, since there is no inheritance involved.

Comment: It is the same. It is still a class attribute, not an instance attribute. A parent class in this case, but still the exact same situation.

Comment: To answer the question: No.

Comment: @dbr: Great dupe target, wish I had found that one. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`list_of_secrets` is scoped to the class here. You want to instead attach it to `self` in `__init__`

```
  def __init__(self):
      self.list_of_secrets = []
```

Answer (score 1):

You never define `self.list_of_secrets`. You only define `F.list_of_secrets`, which is entirely different. Do this instead:

```
class F:
  """An abstract class"""
  def __init__(self):
    self.list_of_secrets = []

  def getSecret(self):
    return self.list_of_secrets
```